# Rotating Div --links not active on flipped side in Chrome

Tags: html, google-chrome, css, webkit

I have a rectangle setup where when you click the main area, it does an animation of it flipping over to reveal the other side of it. This all works correctly.

At the top of each side are links, which display and work properly in Firefox, but in Chrome when it is flipped to reveal the back, the links at the top don't work (they're inactive), and although not visible, the links from the front are active. In the fiddle below, you'll see that I've set up a JS alert on each link to make it clear which one is being clicked. In Chrome, you'll see that neither 'BackLeftLink' or 'BackRightLink' are active. However, if you move your mouse below each of them, you'll see the mouse go active and clicking will show the alert from the front. For some reason the links from the front are coming through the back...as under 'BackRightLink' the link for 'FrontLeftLink' is active, and under 'BackLeftLink' its the link for 'FrontRightLink'.

http://jsfiddle.net/adRP4/3/

Any ideas as to what is causing this problem? Strange that it works perfectly fine in FF, but incorrectly in Chrome...makes me wonder if its related to the webkit css being used in the rotate..?

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

**EDIT** According to others, it seems to work properly in Chrome 20... Unfortunately I need to ensure it works in Chrome 19 (and under) for those who do not yet have Chrome 20. Any suggestions as to what might be causing this problem, and what I can try to do to correct it? Here is a quick screencast of what is happening to me in Chrome: http://screencast.com/t/2QgbceIDA ...desperate to get this fixed, as I need it to work for everyone in FF and Chrome.

Comment: Works fine in Chrome 20 for Windows.

Comment: Hi Marcel--I just checked my Chrome version, and its at 19.0...and I'm having the problem (on Windows XP). Are you sure that when you clicked the links on the back it displayed the proper label in the alert box?? Still not working for me, and I have Chrome set to auto-update, so other people with similar settings will be experiencing the same thing as me. Appreciate you taking a look.

Comment: Works for me. The problem for you might be related to graphics drivers (I have no idea though, just guessing).

Comment: Weird! Just check on a colleagues computer, and doesn't work for him either...although he has the exact same laptop and system image.... So frustrating, as I need to make sure that this works for anyone in FF or Chrome. Any other suggestions as to what may cause this would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Quick screencast showing how it doesn't work for me in Chrome, since it is apparently working for others: http://screencast.com/t/2QgbceIDA

Comment: Here's a screencast of it working in Chrome 20 (a beta) for Windows. http://www.screenr.com/XUl8

Answer (score 0):

Your example is extremely complicated. Take a look at my example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/USRFobiwan/Kp6S9/2/). It has multiple css3 effects like blur, flip and grow and with a view lines of jquery code.